# Node readFile path must be a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-descriptor

Documentation for `fs.readFileSync` is

```
file <String> | <Buffer> | <Integer> filename or file descriptor
```

But

```
require('fs').readFile(0);
```

causes the error

```
TypeError: path must be a string
at TypeError (native)
at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:250:11)
at repl:1:15
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
```

Given an ("Integer") file descriptor, how do I read from it?

Comment: May be relevant: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5862

Answer (score 0):

```
> require('fs').readFileSync(0);
Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, fstat
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.fstatSync (fs.js:977:18)
at tryStatSync (fs.js:462:13)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:12)
at repl:1:15
at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:313:29)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
```

Node version 6.7.0.

Comment: I have 4.3.2, but does that matter? Docs say "Added in: v0.1.29". Is there a way to get the documentation for my version?

Comment: [This version](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.3.2/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) supports file descriptors. Are you sure you don't have something like `nvm` messing with versions?